# Parse a name out of a string

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

There are many server logs that need to be analyzed. Every log message is a string and I'm looping though those stings.

Problem:

I need to see if the string matches the pattern

*some text* **Job** *some_one_word_name* **has finished, status** *some more text*

I need to save the word between words **Job** and **has finished**. In this particular case (see below) I would save the *EgiMmsWellHdr*

```
 Seq_Loading_SOR_to_Landing..JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Job EgiMmsWellHdr has finished, status = 1 (Finished OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
s='Job EgiMmsWellHdr has finished'
awk -F 'Job | has finished' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
EgiMmsWellHdr
```

And using pure BASH:

```
[[ "$s" =~ "Job "([^[:blank:]]+)" has finished" ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
EgiMmsWellHdr
```

Comment: Anubhava, how can I add a comma to the end of the outputted name using the awk method in case there is a pattern match?

Comment: To add a comma in output you can do: `awk -F 'Job | has finished' '{print $2 ","}' <<< "$s"`

Comment: if grep -q 'has finished, status'  <<<$message; then  jobs_string=$jobs_string`awk -F 'Job | has finished' '{print $2","}' <<< "$message"`; fi;    - thats how i made it. Hope it is not too bad

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu grep

```
grep -oP ": Job \K.*(?=has finished)" log.file

EgiMmsWellHdr
```

or

```
grep -oP "(?<=: Job ).*(?=has finished)" file
```

Seems you don't support -P and -o option, try this sed command

```
sed -n 's/.*: Job \(.*\) has finished.*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: are you sure that will give required output?

Comment: Seems your grep is not gnu grep, and don't support -P and -o option, try sed command in my updates

Comment: I dont think that is required

Comment: your original one, with just grep

Comment: So I have pointed at beginning, need gnu grep, maybe need higher version, what's your grep version? `grep -V |head -1`

Comment: +1 all commands working for me..have learned different option in `grep`

Comment: Thanks, at least get one confirmed.

Comment: @BMW I think you say right...OP and other have not gnu grep or older version.

Comment: Sorry man. Works for me as well. It is just that this bash scripting is not my thing and I just used the awk method, because it worked for me straightaway

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[root@server1]# str="Seq_Loading_SOR_to_Landing..JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Job EgiMmsWellHdr has finished, status = 1 (Finished OK)"
[root@server1]# echo $str | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -f3 -d " "
EgiMmsWellHdr
```

Comment: I think "There are many server logs that need to be analyzed. Every log message is a string and I'm looping though those stings." is the thing which says output is a line

Comment: anyways he got the answer, we can stop thinking about it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash regular expressions:

```
re="Job (\w+) has finished" 
while read line
do 
    [[ "$line" =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done <<<"Seq_Loading_SOR_to_Landing..JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Job EgiMmsWellHdr has finished, status = 1 (Finished OK)"
```

output:

```
EgiMmsWellHdr
```

The `\w` is shorthand for the characters `a-z` and `A-Z`.
Instead of the `<<<` which I used, you could indirect a file using `< filename`.